# How to convert a string to time in python3 with default values?

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to convert an input string to date-time value, but some parts of the time can be missing.
Do I need to write the code which can handle these missing parts, or is there an existing function which can do it?

For example:

```
time.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

It will working only if the input contains all fields, but not, the time contains only the hours.
(O.K., I can write a short code for this, but... DRY :) )

Answer (score 1):

How about using try-except for that

```
try:
  t = time.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
except:
  t = time.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If parsing with time fails, then code tries to parse only with date.

Comment: Yes. But not so trivial. What if I get 2021-02-23 1:1?  (=today, 1:01AM)
And I repeat: I can write this verrry complex code, but why to do it if there is an existing funcion? (DRY!)

Comment: It is basicly impossible to write a parser which takes any date string as an input and gives right output. What date is 02/03/2021. Second of March or third of February. Answer depends where you are from.

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Yes invested time for the nothing.
Idióták gyülekezete.